# Visual Studio Error List is hidden

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008

I am using Visual studio 2008 and for some reason when I started today my code is not compiling. I am getting the standard 'Build Failed' message but the Error List is not showing. when I select Error List from the View menu nothing happens.

The output window shows up fine and so does the to do window.

Has anyone seen this before?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's a new one for me.

Go to `Tools` > `Import and Export Settings` and export all your settings to a file for safe keeping.

Then go in there again and reset everything. Report back if that helped. If it did, try importing your settings again to see what happens.

Comment: Weird, 

when i added everything back i got an error: Error 1:  Menu and Command Bar Customizations: The version of command bar settings being imported is not supported. All the command bar settings have been ignored.

Its odd because im prety sure i havent changed any settings, just running on default.

Comment: Maybe some other addin messed up the settings...or maybe it was one of these http://www.encyclopediadramatica.com/index.php/Computer_Gremlins

Comment: I think it might be a gremlin coz now testdriven.NET isnt working. I can just tell that this is gunna be one of those uber productive days

Comment: @Aaron, it looks like u gotta do a reinstall of VS08

Answer (score 14):

Window > Reset Window Layout

Answer (score 7):

Just Type:

> CTRL+\+E

(without the + sign)

Comment: This worked great and didn't perturb my other settings.  Thanks @Shahar.

Answer (score 1):

In my case VS2015 was finding errors but wasn't displaying what are the errors, basically Error List tab was empty. But checking Output tab i found errors and clicking on them opened up the file which had errors, also errors started to show up in Error List tab as well afterwards.

Answer (score -1):

delete  hidden .vs folder in the project folder then close and re-launch your Visual Studio